# Hidden HTML Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, security, iframe

I have a page with iframe, to simplify this case lets assume that it looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="http://example.com"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Assume that the page is on the Internet and you enter it. It loads http://example.com inside the iframe.

I want to change this so that you couldn't see the http://example.com because you can open this adress only using my page not just putting http://example.com in second tab of webbrowser.

I see http://example.com in page source (right click -> page source)
I also see in the network in developer tools that the browser makes request to http://example.com. So I just can copy this address and open it in new webbrowser tab.

What should I do to make it impossible for you to know the address: http://example.com

Comment: That is impossible....

Comment: It is impossible because of A: you cannot hide iframe src, even with some javascript or Ajax request, B: you cannot hide request going throught the network and visible in every webbrowser's developer tools ?

Comment: One time use URLs are the solution... or have the page detect that it is in an iframe, if not redirect...

Comment: Unfortunatelly page in iframe is 3rdparty product and it won't check if it is inside ifame...and I must protect it on my side so as Internet user could not open it without my application. This 3rd party product is another web applciation having its own http address (example.com) So i must do something like @Al Katawazi said. On the other side, the page inside the iframe is not static, it is interactive - so it is a form that you can fill with data (name, surname etc). Then inside the frame you could submit it. If it was not interactive, I would not use iframe and create it on the server side.

Comment: If it is interactive ... what can be done?

Comment: Nothing can be done if you need to include it and you do not control that page.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is if you screen scrape the page in your code and serve up the html yourself. So it would look like this:

1. Someone makes a request to your page
2. Before you serve the page in your back end code you grab the html on
   example.com
3. Serve up the html that comes out of the back end request

This may not be formatted properly though because you are missing css or lose functionality because you are missing js but you just need to make sure you include that stuff.

Comment: So there won't be any iframe in the solution? The network traffic also wouldn't have any request to http://example.com?

Comment: @michealAtmi if you are able to look at the network logs... This answer says to grab it from the server and send it down.... not have the clientside do it.

Comment: I want to protect it against Internet users, on the server side it can be in some logs.. As I udernstand, the page should render on the server side and be appended to response... Well I use Angular/React + nodejs to render pages so maybe it is possible.

Comment: Unfortunatelly page in iframe is 3rdparty product and it won't check if it is inside ifame... 
Guys as I understand it is possible to render some part of a final page on the server side (using even many 

different http addresses for the parts) and return it to the browser and Internet user won't know what was the addresses of 

the parts of the final page. But what if it is forms application - so you fill a form inside iframe, its not static, it is 

interactive... Is it possible to do it without iframe then?

Answer (score 0):

An IFrame is client-side.

This means for the browser to render the IFrame, it must be visible to the client web-browser.

The only way to hide it is for you to develop a web proxy.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="grab_secret_site.php"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here, the code within `grab_secret_site.php` would make an HTTP request to `http://example.com` to grab the HTML. [An example here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17747993/413180). However, bear in mind that any resources won't load unless you rewrite them.

e.g.

```
<img src=icon.jpg />
```

Will point to icon.jpg on your site, not on `example.com`.

If you don't want the page to be loaded without the parent frame, you could create a session variable (e.g. PHP session) in the outer page, which is then checked within the IFrame. If it doesn't exist, redirect the user back to the outer page.

Answer (score -1):

There is a header - X-Frame-Options that allows you to block opening page in iframe, but in this way I think It's impossible.